# When Dragging my C# form, it teleports into the top left corner

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

when i drag the custom nav bar from my c# form in maximized mode, i set the WindowState to normal, and the form teleports into the top left corner, this is currently my dragging code:

```
private void TopBarNav_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        isDragging = true;
        offset = e.Location;
    }
}
private void TopBarNav_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        ExpandButton.IconChar = IconChar.Expand;
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
        Point newLocation = new Point(
        Cursor.Position.X - offset.X,
        Cursor.Position.Y - offset.Y
    );

    this.Location = newLocation;
    }
}

private void TopBarNav_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }
}
```

[before dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dznOA.png)

[After dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSIjQ.png)

i tried a lot of things, including teleporting the form to my cursor, but that just didnt really good for the User Experience

Comment: When you do `this.Location = newLocation;`, what is the value of `newLocation`? If it's 0,0, that's the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: Cursor.Position is an absolute position, e.Location is a relative position.  Use this.PointToScreen() to convert the relative position to the absolute position.

Comment: Note that you are creating and not releasing a new region on each mouse move tick.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the form's Location property to the new location instead of setting the Cursor.Position.X and Cursor.Position.Y properties. This will prevent the form from teleporting to the top left corner when the WindowState is set to Normal.

The updated code should look like this:

```
private void TopBarNav_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        isDragging = true;
        offset = e.Location;
    }
}
private void TopBarNav_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        ExpandButton.IconChar = IconChar.Expand;
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 20, 20));
        Point newLocation = new Point(
        this.Location.X + e.X - offset.X,
        this.Location.Y + e.Y - offset.Y
    );

    this.Location = newLocation;
    }
}

private void TopBarNav_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        isDragging = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "instead of setting the Cursor.Position.X and Cursor.Position.Y properties", uh, that's not what the OP is doing. Did you write this answer your self or have some AI write it for you?

Comment: yea, i also had that exact thing in my code once, and even tried it again. still it teleports into the top left corner for some reason